# Weird entities in the URL breaks the link when using file_get_contents

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents

I'm trying to save an image, with a link that includes: `"r%c3%a9glisse"`

When translated, it will be displayed: `"réglisse"`.

The weird thing is, when I'm using the provided link with `file_get_contents`, it gets a HTTP 404 error, file not found.

I've tried several methods to encode/decode the link and so on, but without much luck.
So I'm wondering if anyone here knows how to solve this issue.

Comment: Could You provide us the link that You can open in browser and it works?

Comment: It's urlencoded UTF-8. Would it work when sent as Latin-1 character? -- There's no generic answer to that. Depends on the server and filesystem encoding.

Comment: do you need to keep these utf8 characters in your file? otherwise you can transliterate it (latin) for safety.

Comment: To be specific, the link is "http://images.asos.com/inv/media/1/5/8/4/1964851/r%c3%a9glisse/image1xl.jpg"

I can't really clean out any content as I need the exact link. I'm not trying to save my own file, but someone else file.

Answer (score 0):

To check which is the file the is not found, check your web server access_log and error_log.
The problem may be that you are trying to file_get_contents() a "url encoded" uri. Try to open it "url decoded":

```
file_get_contents(urldecode("r%c3%a9glisse"));
```

Comment: It wont give any errors if I'm using the url encode, but it wont get saved properly, because image width/height is not able to get identified for some reason.
Any ideas?

Comment: with file_get_content() you have the binary string representation of your image. If the HTTP/404 is solved with the clean uri your mission should be done. What do you mean with "wont get saved properly"?

Comment: The link exists, it doesn't return a HTTP/404, but it wont get the image properties. When using PHP function getimagesize, it does not return any width/height values. Thats what I mean by not being saved properly.